# problem makepkg was unable to build with conky-lua

Tags: linux, arch-linux, yaourt

Since yesterday, i have a problem and i can't install conky-lua.
I have the errors belows and i have tried to install others package and change my pkgbuild but nothing change.

When I try : `yaourt -S conky-lua`

I get the following error:

> ```
> -> ERROR : A failure occured in build() 
> Aborting ...
> -> ERROR : Makepkg was unable to build conky lua.
> ```

Comment: This is an arch specific question You should probably ask for help on arch. Or on the page for the aur package you're trying to install.

Comment: And looking at the aur page for this package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/conky-lua/  It is hasn't been building for a while and the maintainer show no interest in updating it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to contact the actual maintainer to took maintainership. While I've been looking at this package, I created an upgraded PKGBUILD you can find [here](https://github.com/fcolista/aur/tree/master/conky-lua)

You can download the PKGBUILD then run:

```
 makepkg -si PKGBUILD
```